# WinSQL ORDER BY alphanumeric DB2 syntax

Tags: db2, db2-400, winsql

I have the following set of data:

```
33
5A
5B
12
34A
2
34B
2B
11
10
12A
```

When I run the following SQL in WinSQL:

```
with input (f) as ( 
values ('33'), ('5A'), ('5B'),('12'), ('34A'),('2'), ('34B'), ('2B'), ('11'), ('10'), ('12A')
  )
SELECT f 
FROM input
ORDER BY f
```

I get the following result:

```
10
11
12
12A
2
2B
33
34A
34B
5A
5B
```

I would however want the result to be in this order:

```
2
2B
5A
5B
10
11
12
12A
33
34A
34B
```

I have tried the following:

```
with input (f) as ( 
    values ('33'), ('5A'), ('5B'),('12'), ('34A'),('2'), ('34B'), ('2B'), ('11'), ('10'), ('12A')
  )
SELECT 
f
FROM input
ORDER BY CAST(CASE
                 WHEN f LIKE '[0-9]' THEN LEFT(CONCAT(0,f),1)
                 WHEN f LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN LEFT(CONCAT(0,f),1)
                 WHEN f LIKE '[0-9][0-9]%' THEN LEFT(f ,2)
                 ELSE NULL 
              END AS INT), f
```

But it doesn't work.

NOTE: This is for DB2 and all SQL-server functions (such as PATINDEX, SIGNED/UNSIGNED) are not available.

Comment: IS the Db2-server running on Z/OS, or i-Series, or Linux/Unix/Windows?  The collating sequence determines the sorting order.

Comment: Do all of your values follow this pattern: `[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]?`?

Comment: The DB2-server is running on iSeries. @mao

Comment: Yes. @mustaccio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(replace(replace(replace(f,'A',''),'B',''),' ','') AS INT), f
```

(i.e. construct a sort field by getting rid of the non-numeric elements & converting to numeric, and then tie-break using the original value).